# React syntax highlighter performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, infinite-scroll, web-worker

I am using the react syntax highlighter library and it works great, the problem starts in formatting strings over 8000 lines of JSON,
it takes too long and it freezes the app, I am trying to find a useful way to make it faster so that it will not freeze the app.

- I've tried to implement infinite scroll with the react syntax highlighter library and it didn't go well because they don't support that kind of functionality and trying to make it custom for my usage didn't go well also.
- It comes to my mind to maybe use web worker but I've thought it might be an overkill for this and it won't be useful in some use cases.